# Assign a non-registered user to a user group (under a generic user) with a button click

Tags: joomla

I have three buttons: Member (of the organisation, not site), Former Member and Companies.
I would like to change the group of the non-registered guest on the site to the group which they click on. In other words, with one button click log the guest into (a random/pre-made account in) a certain group. I do not want to make them have to log in manually in order to assign them to a certain group.

However, I am unsure how to approach this problem. Could anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you should mix joomla user groups into this mix, it does not really make sense as long as you do not actually intend to log in your users with user and password. If your question is how to present different content to users based on which button they click, here is how I would approach the problem:

In your template, in the index.php - file, check to get the type of user:

```
<?php
$app=JFactory::getApplication();
$membertype=$app->getUserStateFromRequest('com_content.membertype', 
'membertype','member'); 
?>
```

- Make your three buttons links like this: index.php?membertype=member , index.php?membertype=former , index.php?membertype=companies 
  ( You can have the links point directly to the start menu item for the different member types, just remember to add the membertype= - for the different types. )

Now, also in the template index.php, load menu modules depending on the member type:

```
<?php
switch($membertype){
  case 'member': 
  case 'former': 
  case 'companies': 
  ?>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="membermenu_<?php echo $membertype; ?>" 
    style="xhtml" />
  <?php
  break; 
}
?>
```

You can load other modules this way, depending on how much of your content should differ depending on the member type.

In templatedetails.xml, you can add the new module-positions membermenu_member, membermenu_former, membermenu_companies in the positions-section. This will allow you to select the dynamic module positions from the module administration area.

Finally make different menus for the different menu types, and display the menus in different menu modules and module-positions as described above.

regards Jonas